# Detecting cell change events on different sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook which has two sheets. In either sheet, cell A1 calls a function and asynchronously the data is returned X seconds later to the Excel cache. Then, once this data is loaded, I have an array function starting A2 which pastes the data into the sheet.

I would like to automate this. I have written basic `Workbook_SheetChange` functions, but could someone please show me an example where I can check the sheet name, that caused the change?

Comment: @PeterAlbert your deleted answer (two events in the particular sheets) looks more efficient to me than running a global event which could be hugely wasteful. Suggest you undelete this (I had upvoted), but remove the part re "sheet speficic"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if i understand what you need exactly, but you can catch the `SheetChange` event on at the `Workbook` level as well. Sample:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
  If (TypeOf Sh Is Worksheet) Then
    Debug.Print "SheetChange occured in sheet [" & Sh.Name & "] in range [" & Target.Address & "]"
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Please use full English (*you* not *u*) to make your description more readable.